# Subset data frames in a list meeting a particular changing condition

Tags: r, data.table, subset, apply, lapply

Let's asume I have 2 data frames (`d1` and `d2`) in a list (`my.ls`). I want to subset each of the data frames following a condition (e.g. variable `c` equals certain letters such as `l`, `m` and `n`) and save all those subset data frames in a different list.

I can do it using `lapply` for each condition but it is quite verbose. Is it possible to do it in a smarter way besides a `for loop`? Maybe with `mapply`?

```
d1<-data.frame(a=5:1, b=c(rep(2006, times=4),NA), c = letters[10:14])
d2<-data.frame(a=1:5, b=c(2007, 2007, NA, NA, 2007), c = letters[12:16])  

my.ls <- list(d1 = d1, d2 = d2)

my_ls_l <- lapply(my.ls, subset, c=="l")
my_ls_m <- lapply(my.ls, subset, c=="m")
my_ls_n <- lapply(my.ls, subset, c=="n")

my_ls_all <- c(my_ls_l,my_ls_m,my_ls_n)

c_values <- c("l","m","n")

  # Bit of code that does not work
my_ls_smart <- mapply(subset,my.ls,c_values)
```

Comment: You mean `lapply(my.ls, function(i) i[i$c %in% c('l', 'm', 'n'),])`?

Comment: @Sotos that would yield a list of 2 data frames where `c` is equal to `l`, `m` OR `n`. I was thinking on getting 6 data frames, `d1` with `c==l`, `d1` with `c==m`, ..., `d2` with `c == n`

Comment: Fwiw, maintaining and creating separate data frames that have identical columns is almost always a bad idea in R... I'd just do `library(data.table); rbindlist(my.ls, id="src")[c %in% c_values]` and stop there.

Comment: @Frank Totally agree, this is just the last step to present the output in the way the client wants it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution. We first use `lapply` to subset and then `split` on var `c`. To remove 0 length data frames, we use `Filter(nrow,...)`

```
lapply(my.ls, function(i) {x <- i[i$c %in% c('l', 'm', 'n'),]; 
                           Filter(nrow, split(x, x$c))
                           #or avoid Filter by split(x, x$c, drop = TRUE) (from @Nate)
                           })
```

Comment: or we could use `split(x, x$c, drop = TRUE)` and not call `Filter`

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
library(purrr)

c_values %>% map(function(x) map(my.ls, ~subset(., c == x)))

[[1]]
[[1]]$d1
  a    b c
3 3 2006 l

[[1]]$d2
  a    b c
1 1 2007 l


[[2]]
[[2]]$d1
  a    b c
4 2 2006 m

[[2]]$d2
  a    b c
2 2 2007 m


[[3]]
[[3]]$d1
  a  b c
5 1 NA n

[[3]]$d2
  a  b c
3 3 NA n
```

Explanation: You `map` each value in `c_values` into a `map` function that iterates over each `dataframe` subsetting it for each `value` in `c_values`.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with `mapply`

```
#your data
d1<-data.frame(a=5:1, b=c(rep(2006, times=4),NA), c = letters[10:14])
d2<-data.frame(a=1:5, b=c(2007, 2007, NA, NA, 2007), c = letters[12:16])  
my.ls <- list(d1=d1, d2=d2)
c_values <- list(c("l","m", "n"))
#result
lapply(mapply(function(i,j){subset(i, c %in% j)}, my.ls, c_values, SIMPLIFY=F),
   function(x) split(x, x$c, drop = T))
```